# Different callback inside the loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback

I have problem with iterating in array inside callbacks. But it's specific problem.

I have a loop:

```
arr.forEach(function(value, index, array){});
```

Inside the loop I call some asynchronous function:

```
arr.forEach(function(value, index, array)
{
   asFun1(function(i, val){ return function (param1, param2)
   {      
   };}(index, value));
});
```

After callback is fired, I need to set up new callback for the object and then call another asynchronous function:

```
arr.forEach(function(value, index, array)
{
   asFun1(function(i, val){ return function (param1, param2)
   {   
      obj.callback = (function(in, v){ return function (param3, param4)
      {
           //make something
      };}(i, val))   
      obj.asFun2();

   };}(index, value));
});
```

So, to solve the problem I implemented in obj class callback array and iterator. And in the loop I'm not setting the callback, just adding in the array. And when the first callback fires, I command to obj iterator go to the next callback:

```
arr.forEach(function(value, index, array)
{
   asFun1(function(i, val){ return function (param1, param2)
   {   
      obj.callback.addCallback(function(in, v){ return function (param3, param4)
      {
         obj.nextCallback();
         //make something
      };}(i, val))   
      obj.asFun2();

   };}(index, value));
});
```

But when I test it, the value and the index is last in array. I've tried a lot of ways to solve it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I can have only one obj in all frontend.

Comment: That's a strange layout of nested functions, are you calling the `return function ...` ?

Comment: Yes, I call it to give needen index and value in callback with another parameters, It works fine with the first as function, but with the second one - no.

Comment: `in` is a reserved word.

Comment: I don't have the same code, this is what i wrote for the simple example.

Comment: *Where* is the "value and the index" the last from the array? Please also show us how you have implemented `obj.asFun2`, `obj.nextCallback` and `obj.callback.addCallback`